# Flow error: Cannot call `Object.entries(...).reduce` because `...` [1] is incompatible with mixed [2] in index 1 of the second argument

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am pretty new to Flow and I am probably missing something very basic here.

I have an object of a certain format which I am converting to another format. This could have been done in multiple ways, but I chose to use Object.entries to get an array with key/value pairs and then a reducer function handling the entries array, like this:

```
 const langContent = { // The input object
  someKey: {
    en: 'Some en value',
    nb: 'Some nb value'
  },
  someOtherKey: {
    en: 'some other en Value',
    nb: 'some other nb Value'
  }
}

const useLanguages = ['nb', 'en']

const result = Object.entries( langContent ).reduce( ( obj, [key, val] ) => {

  useLanguages.forEach( ( langKey ) => {
    if ( ! obj[langKey] ) obj[langKey] = { translation:{} }
    obj[langKey].translation[key] = val[langKey]
  } )

  return obj
}, {} )

// Expected output object in the form of { en: translation: {someKey: 'some en value'}}
```

The pure js works like expected: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kesteinbakk/fbeyagoh/1/)

However, when trying to use Flow for type checking (and I have spent some time trying to figure out how to do this), I keep getting the error in the header. Here are some of my attempts:

[FlowTry1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAyAhgHYDmA0nlmALxgDkpARo2AD5N6mPrb4wAUVIYATgEs8AZ2q0G08RIqZcBEUpkA1YjACuBBgG8wAbRIU5AXQBcYRZIpgAvvzVgAkqRx6MAeRYAK3owE1MNSRlrMDsIqWkdfQJXVUE-Xx9-IJCwiyoaKxjQsHEyaRhiDAk4UjswuKiCoodlcmcXFzdBACU8ABM9AGM8MQBhPTEAQTFyEPDRSNkaABphBfjEgytUgl6B4bEABTE8ADdp2YZ0jEyAwK7d-qGRgDE9UkGQgAowPeejk7nGarP4HcZTGZgACU9AAfGBrrcguhUIMaoowABbLB5PTEcgyIrTMTELAAHjycnhDFMzDYq0YPEY21R6IwYAqFFGNQwPHZdi8SOCxlQYHscExeDkdVFYAAkDw7IwAMoSginXQGRjLWVi1hK1WSsBwDAACxGYA1ST4YucOrF0jVfjNI2loV1YEVTEdks2eG1Hv13rVfptnRSaNIGJO+wtDB+cCCdlBI2OZwuq1MAGsVpbdIVk08wRMLtCiojfHc4e7ZdjcfiZAA6KBwMRCYiDU0-H6c-K0GF0eFGD0SKBgH4AQmNQVMveiMMTgVnZD7hWMJRJUYqVRqNiM7VcYrFi+XlgKjdKW8q1VI2aaDCtp9XsvaUPQYpOGAmpGn9wjbLAE5HQmYZpHLDJK2yK4gjwQYMEbPlFh7FduVEPloUbGNnh+LCDlWfdoXQUAwCgd44JvEoZAwFMxDJPxC1jAF02BMBJgY-5wQueEvkXOw-EzHMsFWK1bFYmE+IgrJgmHMU6xXPECWkZtW3bTtuw5Fc5DLQd3SPMBR3HMApxPOcmgXGdTKwNdikvcpr13AjDyPEzNPPWztxvO8rJCR9LO2W1CI-PAvzEH9F1QVwUFQIA)

[FlowTry2](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAyAhgHYDmA0nlmALxgDkpARo2AD5N6mPrb4wAUVIYATgEs8AZ2q0G08RIqZcBEUpkA1YjACuBBgG8wAbRIU5AXQBcYRZIpgAvvzVgAkqRx6MAeRYAK3owE1MNSRlrMDsIqWkdfQJXAQI-Xx9-IJCwiyoaKxjQsHEyaRhiDAk4UjswuKiCoodlcmcXF1VBACU8ABM9AGM8MQBhPTEAQTFyEPDRSNkaABphBfjEgyt0VEGaxTAAWyw8vWJyGSLpsWIsAB48uQA+OeY2VcYeRm3d-YwwCoUUY1DA8f52LyZALBYyoMD2OCHPByOpwsAASB4dkYAGVEQQAG66AyMZZo+GsbF4pFgOAYAAWIzARKSfHhzjJ8Ok+L8DJGKNC5LAWKY3KRmzwpKFlNF+IlbM6rlQUD0pEGVRqYDE-SGIzufjs6QwUKCq0mdl6A2GYwm03ILwAFHAgobVqYANYrZm6WxgSYASiKRpNwSMaOOp3OMgAdFA4GIhMRBvSHWBU4D8rRA3QXmH4fCJFA02AAIS0oKmDPRQPOwKVsiZwrGEo3UjlSrVWpGdqufPlutVgrR0ptioa0gepoMFn1ywFNHtf1o7UYCakfuoJV7Nv-bXcibDaRBjK+aEhaF4dXRsGLdMN4GiMFgf3R7VWvCpt+6sSrbvPnaoEAA)

[FlowTry3](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAyAhgHYDmA0nlmALxgDkpARo2AD5N6mPrb4wAUVIYATgEs8AZ2q0G08RIqZcBEUpkA1YjACuBBgG8wAbRIU5AXQBcYRZIpgAvvzVgAkqRx6MAeRYAK3owE1MNSRlrMDsIqWkdfQJXAQI-Xx9-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-eqsg4fOg6BAA)

(It is a lot more time consuming for me writing flow types then writing the actual js ;).

The error is in the reducer function and has something to do with Flow expecting the second array item from the Object.entries key/value pair to be "mixed" (I think). But what I want to do is to tell Flow that for this function we can expect an object as the value in the key/value array, something like this: `Type ExpectedCurrentItem = [string, { [string] : string} ] }` 
Or even better: 
`Type ExpectedCurrentItem = [string, { ['en' | 'nb'] : string} ] }`

(Yes, I know I can solve this in another way, for instance using Object.keys() instead, and I have managed to get an alternative solution free of Flow errors, but there is obviously something I don't understand regarding the Flow logic, and it nags me).

Any insights is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of response to this question I rewrote my code in order get rid of the flow error:

```
type LangKeys = 'en' | 'nb'
type LangKeyValObj =  {[string]: string | void}
type LangObj = {[LangKeys] : {translation: LangKeyValObj} }

const useLanguages : $ReadOnlyArray<LangKeys> = [
  'nb',
  'en'
]

const resources : LangObj = useLanguages.reduce( ( obj: LangObj, langKey : LangKeys ) => {
  const trans = Object.keys( langContent ).reduce( ( o: LangKeyValObj, key: string ) => {
    o[key] = langContent[key][langKey]
    return o
  },{} )
  obj[langKey] = { translation: trans }
  return obj
},{} )
```

Comment: As demonstrated [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2133), `Object.keys()` doesn't have the same problem as `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()`. That does not look correct to me but this issue has been debated for years...